# Appium Desktop not capturing elements of a screen, Just keeps loading

Tags: xcode, appium, element, inspector

I am trying to inspect elements of an iOS app using Appium desktop Inspector, the web driver agent gets installed but the screen is not captured and the element tree cannot be viewed.

The problem seems to have occurred after i updated Xcode version to 12.5.[image]

Below are the logs from the server and attached screenshot of the loading wheel on the Appium desktop inspector.

UserInfo={MobileDeviceErrorCode=(0xE800001A), com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace=(
[error] [35m[Xcode][39m   0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001229f43b8 DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 220
[error] [35m[Xcode][39m   1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000122a03c61 __63-[DTDKRemoteDeviceConnection startFirstServiceOf:unlockKeybag:]_block_invoke + 626
[error] [35m[Xcode][39m   2   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000122a03320 __48-[DTDKRemoteDeviceConnection futureWithSession:]_block_invoke_3 + 22
[error] [35m[Xcode][39m   3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001229f64f8 __DTDKExecuteInSession_block_invoke_2 + 35
[error] [35m[Xcode][39m   4   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001229f5bda __DTDKExecuteWithConnection_block_invoke_2 + 218
[error] [35m[Xcode][39m   5   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001229f5ad7 __DTDKExecuteWithConnection_block_invoke + 106
[error] [35m[Xcode][39m   6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff202cb7e6 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
[error] [35m[Xcode][39m   7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff202d85ae _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 60
[error] [35m[Xcode][39m   8   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010f86848a DVTDispatchBarrierSync + 208
[error] [35m[Xcode][39m   9   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010f83b65e -[DVTDispatchLock performLockedBlock:] + 60
[error] [35m[Xcode][39m   10  DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001229f59d8 DTDKExecuteWithConnection + 226
[error] [35m[Xcode][39m   11  DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001229f639c DTDKExecuteInSession + 239
[error] [35m[Xcode][39m   12  DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000122a03170 __48-[DTDKRemoteDeviceConnection futureWithSession:]_block_invoke_2 + 131
[error] [35m[Xcode][39m   13  DVTFoundation                       0x000000010f865931 **DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK** + 7
[error] [35m[Xcode][39m   14  DVTFoundation                       0x000000010f86755b __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 1191
[error] [35m[Xcode][39m   15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff202ca603 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
[error] [35m[Xcode][39m   16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff202cb7e6 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
[error] [35m[Xcode][39m   17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff202d15ca _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 606
[error] [35m[Xcode][39m   18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff202d20c0 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 417
[error] [35m[Xcode][39m   19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff202dbbed _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 811
[error] [35m[Xcode][39m   20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff204724c0 _pthread_wqthread + 314
[error] [35m[Xcode][39m   21  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff20471493 start_wqthread + 15
[error] [35m[Xcode][39m ), DVTRadarComponentKey=261622, NSLocalizedDescription=The device is passcode protected.}}, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Please check your connection to your device., DVTRadarComponentKey=261622, NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to start remote service "com.apple.mobile.notification_proxy" on device.}
[error] [35m[Xcode][39m [error] [35m[Xcode][39m 2021-05-01 13:34:38.813 xcodebuild[2354:35831]  DTDKRemoteDeviceConnection: Failed to start remote service "com.apple.mobile.notification_proxy" on device. Error: Error Domain=com.apple.dtdevicekit Code=811 "Failed to start remote service "com.apple.mobile.notification_proxy" on device." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fa167cc2f90 {Error Domain=com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain Code=-402653158 "The device is passcode protected."

Its says device is passcode protected, but it is not.

I performed actions like restarting the phone, restarting my mac, delete web driver agent and reinstalling it, check XCUITest driver for necessary signings and everything looks perfect.

Appreciate if anyone can give any suggestions or tips.

Comment: I also got the same issue, I tried with the old version of the OS on the mobile and it started working, Can you let me know what the version?

Comment: Hey, my iOS version is 14.5

Comment: Found a solution for this issue, using Appium desktop beta version resolved the problem.